# Finding the constant term of a degree $3$ polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, where $a,b,c$ are real constants. If $p(-3)=p(2)=0$ and $p'(-3)<0$, which of the following is a possible value of $c$?

A) $-27$

B) $-18$

C) $-6$

D) $-3$

E) $-\dfrac{1}{2}$

> $\textbf{My attempt at this problem}$: 
>   I drew a rough sketch of the curve on the $xy$-plane. A portion of the degree $3$ curve has a local max to the left of $-3$ and a local min between $-3$ and $2$. When $x> 2$, $p$ is a strictly increasing function, no longer intersecting the $x$-axis.
>
> Since $p(-3)=p(2)=0$, we plug in these integers to get 
>   $$
> p(-3)=(-3)^3 + a(-3)^2+b(-3)+c=0, \\ 
> p(2) =(2)^3 + a(2)^2+b(2)+c=0.  
> $$

There is another root when $x<-3$. 
Is there a trick to solve this problem without so much calculation?

Comment: You're given three unknowns (linearly) and three pieces of information, two equalities and an inequality. You should be able to deduce an inequality in $c$, which (if the question is written well) should leave only one choice. Curiously, this should allow you to eliminate all but the first and last options without doing even a single calculation.

Comment: @davin Thanks. So I'm guessing the calculation is necessary for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, there are three roots, one at $-3$, one at $2$, and one less than $-3$.  Call the last one $r$.  Then the polynomial factors as $(x+3)(x-2)(x-r)$ with $r \lt -3$  Now if you multiply out the constant term....

Answer (score 1):

$p$ has three roots, $-3$, $2$ and $x_0$, say. We have 
$$ p(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = (x+3)(x-2)(x-x_0). $$
So $c = 6x_0$. As, as you said, $x_0 < -3$, A) is the only possibility.

Comment: Very tricky and nice! I thought about factorization, but quickly and too naively threw away the thought... =)